# Error on Advanced Rest Client while sending message

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, advanced-rest-client

My Advanced Rest Client was working perfectly and sending message. Maybe it send 10 messages, but after that it is showing this message. Please tell me whats wrong with it.

Here is the picture of the error
[image]

Here is my message body

```
{
 "to":"/topics/NEWS",
  "data":
  {
    "title":"Eid Notification",
   "img_url":"http://www.pakworkers.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Eid-ul-Fitr-Holidays-Announced-by-Interior-Ministry-of-Pakistan-26-28-June-2017.jpg"
  }

}
```

Comment: What error do you see in that screenshot? If there is an error message, please take the exact text from that screenshot and paste it into your question (and into your favorite search engine too).

Comment: {
"message_id": 
6147845476705658000
The number used in the response is unsafe in JavaScript environment and therefore as a JSON value.

Original value for the number (represented as string) is "6147845476705658209"

This number will not work in web environment and should be passed as a string, not a number.

Read more about numbers in JavaScript.

}

Answer (score 0):

response is 200 OK so no issues while getting response.

Issue is to change message Id in json from number to string in backend rest application.

Comment: So how to do?? Could u please tell me?

Comment: You'e not using the umber in JavaScript, so there is no problem.